# Recursive count SWI-Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to count a whole Europe population using this fucntion:

```
printEuropePopulation(A) :-
    country(_, X, _, _),
    printEuropePopulation(A+X),
    true.
printEuropePopulation(A) :- write(A).
```

And program gives me

> Out of local stack

when I call my func

> printEuropePopulation(0)

Facts looks like:

```
country("Slovenia",20,2009,27300).
country("Finland",338,5238,35500).
country("France",549,60876,33800).
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second argument is not population (in thousands), it is area (in thousands sq. km). Your third argument is population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a recursive predicate I think? It is easier to collect all the facts and then find the sum.

```
total_population(Total) :-
    findall(P, country_population(_, P), Ps),
    list_sum(Ps, Total).
```

In your definition you are taking the area it seems, but I take the population in thousands:

```
country_population(C, P) :- country(C, _, P, _).
```

If you want to find the sum you can do a recursive predicate because now you have all the population counts (the second argument?) in a list.

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([X|Xs], Sum) :-
    list_sum(Xs, S0),
    Sum is S0 + X.
```

Now you can query it to find the sum of the second arguments of `country`

```
?- total_population(P).
P = 68123.
```

But if you are using SWI-Prolog you can also use one library which is called "aggregate" because you can use it to aggregate for example the sum:

```
?- aggregate_all(sum(P), country(_, _, P, _), Total_population).
Total_population = 68123.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. How I can print my final result using your example?

Comment: @Burning what do you mean print final result? When I query as shown in the answer it already prints. Do you want to print it to a printer or to a file?

Comment: no, just to print it on my screen, your code returns me "false" in the output. I`ve tried write result at each step of recursion, and it counts perfect, but i need only final value

Comment: @Burning if it says "false" in output then there is a mistake in your code, when I use your facts and the code in my answer I do not get "false", I only get result like "Population = 12354" for example. Maybe you made mistake in your code?

Comment: You probably wrote different code from code I show in my answer and you introduce errors, or maybe your facts are not like the facts that you show and this is why there are errors and it says "false". When you get "false" this means that Prolog could not find proof for your query but if you expect that your query should succeed then if it fails and says "false" it means you made an error somewhere.

Comment: `country_population(C, P) :- country(C, _, P, _).

total_population(Total) :-

    findall(P, country_population(_, P), Ps),
    list_sum(Ps, Total).

list_sum([X|Xs], Sum) :-

    list_sum(Xs, S0),
    Sum is S0 + X.`

Comment: @Burning maybe there is error, I see missing things in what you show in your comment, does your code compile without errors and warnings? because if you have errors or warnings when you try to compile this means that there are errors in your code that you wrote.

Comment: @Burning this works for me exactly as written but you are missing the first clause of `list_sum/2` Y U NO copy full code from my answer? It should have clause for end condition `list_sum([], 0).`

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it, that was my mistake, your anwer is correct.

Comment: @Burning I am happy I could help